# Did you know...? Where does the question mark go?

Tags: ellipsis, question-marks

Where does the question mark go in 'Did you know...'?

I am trying to punctuate:

> Did you know...
>
> 1% of the population xxxxx
>
> 7% of the population xxxxx
>
> 16% of employers xxxxx etc. etc.

showing a long list of facts.

Do I:

1. Put the ? after the ellipsis (...)
2. Put an ellipsis at the start of each fact and a ? at the end of each fact (some are very long though)
3. Not have a question mark at all

Comment: "Did you know" is a rhetorical question here. Though it should have a Q mark, not putting it doesn't cause big harm.

Comment: This is really a though-provoking question! +1 I guess putting a question mark in the title is optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily gramatical, but…
If you put the question mark right at the end of a long list like that, your audience will have forgotten they were waiting for one.
Putting one at the end of each line wouldn't work, as they are not all questions, but statements.
Putting one at the end of only the first statement would then throw the perceived balance of the rest.

In that circumstance, I would put it right after the ellipsis.

> Did you know…?
>   list
>   list

That then allows your list to be a list of facts, no further question involved.

Using it that way has become quite common in recent times - [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Did%20you%20know%E2%80%A6%3F%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20know%20...%20%3F%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Put the question mark there, and I'd recommend leaving out the ellipsis. **Did you know?** 1% of the population prefers to take a shower wearing flip-flops... etc.

Comment: I spent a lot of time looking in to this and there doesn't appear to be any definitive answer. More preferences. I appreciate all the responses. I was copy checking so I couldn't change what was there (to remove the question and make it a statement), so, I went with: Did you know...? and then listed all the facts as a list underneath (as suggested by Tetsujin). Thank you.